# Unable to update package, because it requires jre1.8 - "Try using --skip-broken". Jre1.8 is already installed on the machine, though

Tags: linux, redhat, centos6, yum, rpm

so I'm unable to run a yum update on one of my machines. It returns the following error:

```
[root@yadayada ~]# yum -y update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ods-filerepo.noarch 0:1.3-110520.0-el6 will be updated
---> Package ods-filerepo.noarch 0:1.3-110852.0-el6 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: jre1.8 for package: ods-filerepo-1.3-110852.0-el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ods-filerepo-1.3-110852.0-el6.noarch (ods)
           Requires: jre1.8
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

However I clearly have the correct version of Java installed on the machine:

```
[root@yadayada ~]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

[root@yadayada ~]# yum install java
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Package jre1.8.0_121-1.8.0_121-fcs.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I'm at a bit of a loss. Does anyone have any idea what I could look at here to fix this? We use internal repositories, but none of the other hosts are facing this issue. This is a very old machine that I've been tasked with recovering and I'm scratching my head as to what could be the cause.

It's on Centos6.9 (not by choice).

Comment: You demonstrated installing `java`, not `jre1.8`.

Comment: The response from the server is "Package jre1.8.0_121-1.8.0_121-fcs.x86_64 already installed and latest version" though so I'm assuming the repo being used conflates Java with jre1.8. I don't know very much about how rpm's/repos work though so I might be wrong.